# Вывод данных из моделей в Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, django, bootstrap, carousel

Есть модель под названием rigs_carousel. Статьи данной модели должны выводится на сайт в виде слайдов Bootstrap Карусели. Проблема в том, что при разных махинациях карусель или вовсе не выводится или слайды накладываются друг на друга. Так же проблема состоит в том, что эта карусель довольно старая (я её давно делал) и с тех пор изменил способ вывода данных на странцу и соответственно возник вопрос, а как вообще этот rigs_carousel подключить к уже готовой странице во views.py Буду очень благодарен за помощь! 
**html файл с carousel:**

```
<!-- Карусель -->

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Индикаторы слайдов карусели -->
  <!-- Я хочу выводить именно 3 самых новых новости на сайт -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Слайды карусели -->
  <div class="carousel-inner ccarousel">
    {% for post in rigs_carousel %}
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="{{ post.image.url }}">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1 class="display-2">{{ post.title }}</h1>
          <h2>{{ post.text }}</h2>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Читать далее</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

  <!-- Переключение между слайдами карусели -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Rig
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ShowRigView(ListView):
    model = Rig
    template_name = 'rigs/rigs.html'
    context_object_name = 'rig'
    ordering = ['-date']
    paginate_by = 15

    def get_context_data(self, **kwards):
        ctx = super(ShowRigView, self).get_context_data(**kwards)
        ctx['title'] = 'MCStore Rigs'
        return ctx

class RigDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Rig
    def get_context_data(self, **kwards):
        ctx = super(RigDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwards)
        ctx['title'] = Rig.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).first()
        return ctx

class CreateRigsView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Rig
    template_name = 'rigs/rig_create.html'
    fields = ['title', 'text', 'image_0', 'image_1', 'image_2', 'version', 'is_vanila', 'price', 'date']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)

class UpdateRigsView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Rig
    template_name = 'rigs/rig_form.html'
    fields = ['title', 'text', 'image_0', 'image_1', 'image_2', 'version', 'is_vanila', 'price', 'date']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)

class DeleteRigsView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Rig
    success_url = '/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и не нашёл решения, поэтому перешёл на slick slider (https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) В русскоязычном Ютубе есть много видео про его настройку, которая к слову очень простая (добавление небольшого количества JS кода)